# Creating dotted lines in array environments with arydshln not working

Tags: lyx, arrays

I'm trying to represent partitioned block matrices in LyX. If I want to separate the blocks using solid lines, I have no trouble making it happen - here's a simple example:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
A & B\\
\hline 
C & D\\
\end{array}\right],
\end_inset
\end_layout
```

To change the separating lines to dotted lines, I include the package arydshln in the preamble

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{arydshln}
```

and replace the | with : and \hline with \hdashline.

Unfortunately, this does not work - the vertical dashed line is simply not visible, and the word \hdashline is visible instead of a horizontal dashed line.

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\left[\begin{array}{c:c}
A & B\\
\hdashline 
C & D\\
\end{array}\right],
\end_inset
\end_layout
```

Is there something else I ought to be doing in addition to what I have done so far? Looking through arydshln's manual has not helped, so I suspect that it is something subtle, and would greatly appreciate pointers.

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: What are `\begin_layout … \end_layout` and `\begin_inset … \end_inset`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know - I have just copied the TeX code. They seem to be present everywhere in the document.

Comment: I asked the question, because without these environments, there's no problem.

Comment: The Formula inset is unavoidable - while my MWE just used A, B C and D, the real problem has equations in each of these blocks. Oddly enough, it seems to work on the app at https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6175, but it does not work in my document.